# Filter request logs in the istio sidecar proxy

Tags: kubernetes, istio, envoyproxy, azure-front-door

I have azure front door sitting on front of a aks cluster which has istio and proxy sidecars injected into each pod.

Azure front door has health probes which hit a request at least once a second due to the number of azure front door endpoints. The number of requests the apps are getting is very high to the point I want to slow the interval It hits with the affect of losing the benefits of front door.

Microsoft suggest to code a telemetry initialiser in dotnet to mark requests as synthetic, however this seems like a massive problem that I would need to get multiple teams to buy into. As well as replicate to multiple languages.

Instead I would like to use an envoy filter to look at the header of the requests and if it matches the front door agent "Edge Health Probe" I would like to completely ignore it.

This would mean I am in control of what logs get sent to the app insights, can roll out a one fix fits all and would not need to involve the Devs.

I have looked to envoy filter but can't really understand how it would work.

Is this possible with envoy filter or does anyone know of a better method?

Thanks
Kevin

Comment: Alternative you could set up a route in a virtualservice that routes all requests with the header to some dummy nginx application. By that the requests are completely decoupled from your workloads. Not sure if I fully understand your question though.

Comment: So basically I use frontdoor in front of each service in the cluster, the number of requests that frontdoor makes to each due to the number of endpoints is so high that our log space runs out of capacity by midday. The requests come with a specific agent header which if I could filter out, as I don't really care about the requests being logged, it would really reduce this. U can see the request logs when you look at the istio proxy logs, they just come as HEAD requests to a health probe page that has been setup. I just want to do a "if agent header == X: then don't log request end"

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/api-filtering-sampling#filtering-itelemetryprocessor here is what Microsoft recommend but obviously this is a coding method that we would need to replicate for diff languages and roll out to numerous applications.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with an `EnvoyFilter`. This example recognizes the header on the ingress gateway and simple sends a 200 response without sending it to the workloads:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: custom-ms-header
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: ingressgateway
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER
      match:
        context: GATEWAY
        listener:
          filterChain:
            filter:
              name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              subFilter:
                name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
      patch:
        operation: INSERT_BEFORE
        value:
          name: custom.ms-header
          typed_config:
            "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua
            inlineCode: |
               function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
                 val = request_handle:headers():get("some-header")
                 if (val and val ~= "some-value") then
                   request_handle:respond({[":status"] = "200"}, "ok")                        
                 end
               end
```

Alternatively you can apply it to match certain workloads

```
[...]
    namespace: my-namespace
spec:
  workloadSelector:
    labels:
      istio: my-worklload
  configPatches:
    - applyTo: NETWORK_FILTER
      match:
        context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
        listener:
          filterChain:
[...]
```

Tough this requires you to apply it to every workload.

Comment: Sorry if indentation is not correct, I wrote this on my smartphone.

Comment: If you have further questions please ask in the comments, I can expand my answer.

Comment: This sounds great and yeah exactly what I wanna do. Do I need to apply this filter in every namespace or in the istio system namespace? It'll be across the board I want this in place.

Comment: The version with the ingress gateway only has to be applied to the namespace where the istio-ingressgateway pod is running, normally the istio-system namespace. the logic will be applied to every request coming in.

Comment: I'll try this late next week and if all good the points are yours! But yeah this looks exactly what I'll looking for

Comment: Great, please let me know if you have problems setting it up or have further questions

Comment: Thinking about it I'm not goina be able to put it fully on the ingress gateway, as they are used by frontdoor to know whether the individual service is running, I just don't want the logs to record... So I think it'll have to be the side car one and I'll have to do some kind of check that the pod is up via a simple ping and then return true or something like that... Would this be similar?

Comment: Can you maybe alter sidecar outbound as im assuming that is what gets recorded on the logs

Comment: Yes you could do a request from the envoy filter and response with this directly. But would that really solve your problem? You still get requests to you main application

Comment: I don't mind getting the requests to the main application its more recording the logs from the frontdoor in to app insights that is causing the main issue (logs are filling up really fast - hence running out of space and just creating "noise") - how would you recommend doing the request from the envoy filter to the application so that i can then just return 200 to the frontdoor and hopefully exclude the actual log request from being saved to app insights. It'll be the app that records that request though, I assume that'll go back out through the proxy though, so could I maybe detect that??

Comment: so ive created an envoy filter but im still getting the same logs come through:
`[2021-08-27T15:12:57.260Z] "HEAD /health/probe HTTP/1.1" 200 - "-" 0 0 1 0 "<ip>" "Edge Health Probe" "e4562752-127b-4d6b-a209-56dc79d20b7d" "<domain_name...>" "127.0.0.1:8080" inbound|8080|| <ip>:59498 <ip>:8080 <ip>:0 outbound_.80_._.svcname.namespace.svc.cluster.local default` - about 50 of them a second.... - how do i know its even doing anything?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. Were you able to fix it?

Comment: No unfortunately not... I tried to get the basics working just to see if I could see the difference, but couldn't Seem to get it working

Comment: So it's not working at all? I checked my example and fixed some intendation. The easiest for testing if it works would be to add a custom header. 
```
            inlineCode: |
               function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
                 request_handle:headers():add("custom", "header")
               end
``` 
That should be working,

Comment: Also you can open the envoy dashboard by running `istioctl dashboard envoy <pod-name>.<namespace-of-pod>` and look into the config dump (http://localhost:15000/config_dump). You should be able to find your filter there.

Comment: I'll give another go next week and see where I get and I'll comment back

Answer (score 0):

am I misunderstanding this but if you want to ignore the request why not simply turn off the health probes?

Or change the interval of the probes from the default 30 seconds to 255 which decreases the requests, also of course the default health probes are HEAD requests so you can easily filter them out.

Comment: I need the heatlh probes as that will let frontdoor know to send to either cluster based on the health probes so disabling them would make that pointless, also increasing the interval although thought of would make the failovwr really really slow. I want to stop the logs actually being recorded in app insights as that's where the problem is occurring. An envoy filter would need to check if the health probe works and return 200 to frontdoor but without the actual log line - if poss